# Why mocking HuggingFace datasets library does not work?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I have a Python function that uses the HuggingFace `datasets` library to load a private dataset from HuggingFace Hub.

I want to write a unit test for that function, but it seems pytest-mock does not work for some reason. The real function keeps getting called, even if the mock structure should be correct.

This is the main function:

```py
def load_data(token: str):
    dataset = load_dataset("MYORG/MYDATASET", use_auth_token=token, split="train")
    return dataset
```

And this is the test function I wrote:

```py
def test_data(mocker):
    # Mocked data
    token_test = "test_token"
    mocked_dataset = [
        {'image': [[0.5, 0.3], [0.7, 0.9]], 'timestamp': datetime.date(2023, 1, 1)},
    ]
    mocker.patch('datasets.load_dataset', return_value=mocked_dataset)

    result = load_data(token_test)

    assert len(result) == 1
```

Could it be that there are some "unmockable" libraries which do stuff under the hood and make their functions impossible to stub?

Comment: Did you have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch? If your module is called my_module (and it does from datasets import load_dataset) then you should patch mocker.patch('my_module.load_dataset'. Let me know if this works so I'll write a proper answer

Comment: @PeterK that was it! Thank you so much! Go ahead with the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official Python documentation has this part: [where-to-patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch?).

If your module is called `my_module`, and it does `from datasets import load_dataset` then you should patch `mocker.patch('my_module.load_dataset'` so that **your** module is using the mock.

Patching `datasets.load_dataset` might be too late, since if the import in your module happened before that instruction, it has no effect.